# Getting Google Spreadsheet data into Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script

I want to import the data from Google Spreadsheet into Firebase Database, using Google Apps Script library access to the Firebase Database.

There is [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-with-a-service-account) that shows how it can be accomplished, I followed these steps and my code in Google Apps Script is here:

```
function updateData() {
  function getFirebaseService(){
    return OAuth2.createService('Firebase')
    // Set the endpoint URL.
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

    // Set the private key and issuer.
    .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

    // Set the scopes.
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database');
  }

  var token = getFirebaseService().getAccessToken();
  Logger.log(token);

}
```

This is my appsscript.json↓

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Hong_Kong",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
      "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
      "version": "33"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "FirebaseApp",
      "libraryId": "1hguuh4Zx72XVC1Zldm_vTtcUUKUA6iBUOoGnJUWLfqDWx5WlOJHqYkrt",
      "version": "30"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
}
```

Necessary oauthScopes has been added.

When I connected the Firebase , the result is '**Error: Access not granted or expired. 454**'.

It's might be AccessToken expired, but after updating the latest `PRIVATE_KEY` and `CLIENT_EMAIL`, the error still show.

I have no idea about it , if someone could give me advices, I'll be grateful.